# SFTP asks for passphrase for unencrypted private key, but WinSCP works fine?

Tags: linux, redhat, sftp, private-key

## Summary:

I want to SFTP a file from one server to another, authorizing with a private-key.

I believe the public key is installed correctly (WinSCP lets me log in with private key), and I deliberately did not create a passphrase when generating the key-pair.... but when I try to SFTP on the command line, I'm prompted for both the non-existent passphrase *and* the user password.

How can I SFTP with just the unwrapped private-key?

## Details:

I have two servers:

- toServer123
- fromServer123

I want to SFTP a file from one server to another, using a private-key login.

1. I generate a public-private key pair using puttyGen:

   - after providing the prompted random movement, I save the public and private key
   - **I leave the passphrase field blank and choose 'yes' when prompted about unencrypted private key**
2. I install the public key on toServer123:

   - I create a user paultest with password 'password123'
   - I test that I can ssh into toServer123 as user paultest
   - I create /home/paultest/.ssh/authorized_keys and add the public key
   - The public key looks like:

     `cat /home/paultest/.ssh/authorized_keys` #=>

     ssh-rsa verylongstringoflettersandnumbersNoNewlines paultest@toServer123
   - I chmod permissions: authorized_keys (644), .ssh (700)
3. I install the private key on the fromServer123:

   - I create dir: /home/support_user/sftp_proc (chmod 700)
   - I upload my_private_key.ppk (chmod 600) to /sftp_proc
   - I create file text.txt in /sftp_proc which just contains "this is a test"
4. as support_user, I try to SFTP to toServer123 from fromServer123:

   ```
   sftp -oIdentityFile=./my_private_key.ppk paultest@toServer123
   ```

**What I expect**:

I get logged into the server without further prompt, since I'm logging in with an unwrapped key file.

**What I get**:

```
Connecting to toServer123...

Unauthorized access to or use of this system is prohibited.
All access and use may be monitored and recorded.

Enter passphrase for key './my_private_key.ppk':
```

I just hit enter, and get:

```
paultest@toServer123's password:
```

**Debugging steps**:

- If I provide the paultest password, the SFTP works - but I don't want to use a password, I want to log in with a private key
- If I try to log in using winSCP and provide the private key, I am able to log in with just that - I get no passphrase or password prompts.

**Question**:

What am I doing wrong, if my goal is to log in without providing a password, and without being prompted for the non-existing passphrase?

**Edit**

my_private_key.ppk looks like:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: rsa-key-20190528
Public-Lines: 6
LOTSOFLETTERSabcSYMBOLS//++ANDNUMBERS123==
Private-Lines: 14
EVENEVENMORELOTSOFLETTERSabcSYMBOLS//++ANDNUMBERS123==
Private-MAC: cf6c5c786f51a623b28eabe226c98dd6faa09787
```

Comment: What does the `./my_private_key.ppk` look like?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I added the format of the .ppk file to the question - does that look correct?

Comment: OK, then the answer by @Romeo is correct.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Right you are - I converted the private key and it worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK `sftp` expect different format of key. The keys of OpenSSH should look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAyGhJBM7lcIZgvTbLG4S2N1oHAIszqAKKysCQY17Fp0dHvL+A
8mVCYwKL0otQfS2FHmmeRfrpLQtaK7R/DFnxfXn8xczpY8Cn6sv+GUjztN0gacOK
Yyiymnfr4mKgSaRIaJDmi3ua8mlddvwtUJFkAt7WrVAgx0z4MkW5jR+riKnT69D+
<snip> 
YFbX0QKBgFTXQ+h79DR4ZwW/f5pop9v8H7GD+g/xRKadgFp4GTKA7RJx64XN/ok+
12+u6pApA8w+ah2K2yoaBIV1d3MatYfUwSJ+0esXTYczBeSXOg6YqrMqjZ4KH2wO
kOyu2/4Dq7VcuK4PSnF1wbd+ZPHffh+YOJIII4iU7fYoRMDHa3tW
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So you should convert your ppk key to RSA key. [Here](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/putty-ppk-vers-openssl-openssh.html) is how to use putty utils to do it

Comment: If a wrong key format is used, it would say *"invalid format"*, and not prompt for a passphrase

Comment: OK, I get *"invalid format"* with OpenSSH 7.7. But if I use an older version of OpenSSH, like 5.3, I indeed get a prompt for a passphrase. +1

Comment: You nailed it - format of the private-key was incorrect. The default private-key generated by puttyGen worked in software like WinSCP, but not in whatever version of SFTP was installed on my server. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl don't worry I will. I am competing the task first, In case there's any extra information I can add into the question before I close it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, fine, I won't add anything else. it's marked answered now. Thanks for your help. Please stop messaging me.